# How can I convert tuple of dictionaries into an organized dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I am pulling an API that retrieves data in the format below.

```
     data = ({'2019-12-20': {'SMA': '216.0037'},
              '2019-12-19': {'SMA': '215.4711'},
              '2019-12-18': {'SMA': '214.9335'},
              '2019-12-17': {'SMA': '214.4074'}})
```

Currently, when I try and run "data = pd.DataFrame(data)", it returns a dataframe with 2 rows that uses each date as a seperate column and gives each row a dictionary as a value (example below).

```
           2019-12-20       |       2019-12-19     |      2019-12-18
 0  "{ 'SMA' : '216.0037' } |  {'SMA': '215.4710"} | {'SMA': '214.9335'}
 1            NaN           |         NaN          |        NaN
```

I would like to figure out how to convert this data into a dataframe following the format below.

```
        date     |   SMA
 ----------------------------
 0  '2019-12-20' | '216.0036'
 1  '2019-12-19' | '215.4711'
 2  '2019-12-18' | '214.9335'
 3  '2019-12-17' | '214.4047'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})
         date       SMA
0  2019-12-20  216.0037
1  2019-12-19  215.4711
2  2019-12-18  214.9335
3  2019-12-17  214.4074
```

Or `from_dict`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,'index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})
                 SMA
2019-12-17  214.4074
2019-12-18  214.9335
2019-12-19  215.4711
2019-12-20  216.0037
```

Answer (score 4):

From your code it looks like data is a dictionary (the outer parenthesis is ignored).

```
data = ({
    '2019-12-20': {'SMA': '216.0037'},
    '2019-12-19': {'SMA': '215.4711'},
    '2019-12-18': {'SMA': '214.9335'},
    '2019-12-17': {'SMA': '214.4074'}
})
assert isinstance(data, dict)
```

If that's the case then the dataframe you want can be generated as follows.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(k, v['SMA']) for k, v in data.items()],
    columns=['date', 'SMA']
)
```

Output:

```
         date       SMA
0  2019-12-20  216.0037
1  2019-12-19  215.4711
2  2019-12-18  214.9335
3  2019-12-17  214.4074
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to achieve this using [pandas.DataFrame.T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T)

> Reflect the DataFrame over its main diagonal by writing rows as columns and vice-versa. The property T is an accessor to the method.

`df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})` will return:

```
         date       SMA
0  2019-12-20  216.0037
1  2019-12-19  215.4711
2  2019-12-18  214.9335
3  2019-12-17  214.4074
```